# Inserting records in temporary table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I declare one table and trying to insert records, but it is taking so much time to insert. This is my temp table :

```
   declare @totalAprovals Table(
         apptype varchar(max)
       , Id varchar(max)
       , empno varchar(max)
       , empname varchar(max)
       , AppliedDate varchar(max)
       , rstatus varchar(max)
       , LeaveType varchar(max)
       , fromdate varchar(max)
       , todate varchar(max)
       , finyear varchar(max)
       , noofdays varchar(max)
       , perdate varchar(max)
       , pertype varchar(max) 
       , TotMin varchar(max)
       , FrmTime varchar(max)
       , ToTime varchar(max)
       , ConDate varchar(max)
       , Amount varchar(max)
       , MaterialDesc varchar(max)
       , EstValue varchar(max)
       , FromYear varchar(max)
       , ToYear varchar(max)
       , AvailedFrom varchar(max)
       , AvailedTo varchar(max)
       , Purpose  varchar(max)
       , FromPlace  varchar(max)
       , ToPlace  varchar(max)
       , ICode  varchar(max)
       , IDesc  varchar(max) 
       , MgrId varchar(max)
```

)

and my insert statement :

```
    insert into @totalAprovals          
     SELECT DISTINCT  'LEAVE' AppType
                    , CRS.applicationId ID
                    , CRS.EmpId EmpNo
                    , ISNULL((
                               SELECT FirstName 
                               FROM Tbl_Emp_M 
                               WHERE EmpId=CRS.EmpId
                               )
                               , CRS.EmpId) EmpName
                    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LA.LeaveDate,103) AppliedDate
                    , (CASE ISNULL((
                                     SELECT top 1 CurStatus 
                                     FROM Tbl_CRS_Leave_AppHis_T 
                                     WHERE stepno=CRS.StepNo-1 
                                     and applicationId=CRS.applicationId  
                                     AND Status=1 
                                     order by StepNo desc),'0')   
                        WHEN '0' THEN 'Applied' 
                            WHEN '1' THEN 'Recommended' 
                            WHEN '2' THEN 'Approved' 
                       END) Rstatus
                    , LT.LeaveName LeaveType
                    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LA.FromDate,103) FromDate
                    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LA.ToDate,103) ToDate
                    , '' FinYear
                    , '' NoOfDays
                    , '' PerDate
                    , '' PerType
                    , '' TotMin
                    , '' FrmTime
                    , '' ToTime
                    , '' ConDate
                    , 0 Amount
                    , '' MaterialDesc
                    , 0 EstValue
                    , '' FromYear
                    , '' ToYear 
                    , ''AvailedFrom
                    , '' AvailedTo
                    , '' Purpose
                    , '' FromPlace
                    , '' ToPlace
                    , '' ICode
                    , '' IDesc
                    , CRS.MgrId    
    FROM   Tbl_Leave_App_T LA
         , Tbl_CRS_Leave_App_T CRS
         , Tbl_Leave_Typ_M LT
         , Tbl_Emp_ServiceDetails_T EMS   
    WHERE  CRS.applicationId = LA.ApplicationId 
    AND    LA.LeaveTypeId = LT.LeaveTypeId 
    and    crs.EmpId = ems.EmpId  
    AND    CRS.Status = 1 
    AND    LA.Status = 1 
    AND    LT.Status = 1 
    and    ems.Status = 1 
    AND    CRS.CurStatus IN ('0') 
    AND    YEAR(LA.LeaveDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
    AND    la.LeaveTypeId not in (9,12) 
    AND  -- LA.ApplicationId LIKE '%LEV%' AND       
           CRS.EmpId = EMS.EmpId 
    and    ems.LocationCode  IN ('101','102','103','104','AHUP') 
    and    crs.MgrId ='xxxxx'
```

It is taking 2 to 3 minutes to execute this. What could be the reason? Am I writing wrong process to insert records?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with inserting itself; I'd guess your select takes too long. Also, you seem to use table variables (even though they have representation in tempdb), not temp tables

Comment: Mr. a1ex07 when i run the only selelct statement, the statement get execute with in 4 to 6 seconds

Comment: Then I'd get rid of `varchar(max)` in table variable definition and replace with something that makes more sense (`varchar(max)` is actually very similar to blob; from your query I think there is absolutely no need to use blob column )

Comment: do you really need max lenght for EVERY varchar field in your temp table? i'm pretty sure that also affects the performance, see here: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/

Comment: The `SELECT` itself only takes 4 to 6 seconds? Does it have a parallel plan when selecting on its own but not when used as a source in the insert statement? What if you replace the table variable with a `#temp` table to allow a parallel plan to be used?

Comment: That is a mess though. Agree with previous comments that you should **not** simply declare all columns as `varchar(max)`. Also suggest using explicit ANSI-92 join syntax.

Comment: @MartinSmith: w/o DDL we may never know...maybe the source tables are also all `varchar(max)` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, actually i replace the declaring the table like 
"declare @totalAprovals Table" to "create table #totalAprovals now it is working superb. Thank you for replying all.

Answer (score 2):

You have a performance problem so investigate it as a performance problem. Use a methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). Follow the [SQL Server PErformance Flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/presentations/archive/2008/04/18/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-and-scalability-flowchart.aspx).

When you post here, always add the **exact** DDL used to create those tables, including all indexes, and capture and link the execution plans.

Most likely is not the `INSERT` the problem, but the `SELECT`. DISTINCT is always a code smell indicating a poorly understood join. The WHERE clause is full of non-sargable predicates.

Comment: Mr. Remus Rusanu, when i execute the select statement it is executed in 3 to 4 seconds

Comment: That changes nothing. You still have a performance problem to investigate, using an appropriate methodology like Waits and Queues. You are asking us to *guess* why it happens. And read [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Hi Remus, i change the declaration of table to crate table now it is working fine. thanks for replying.